# Replace Line with New Line in Python

Tags: python

I am reading a text file and searching data line by line, based on some condition, changing some values in the line and writing it back into another file. The new file should not contain the old Line. I have tried the following, but it did not work. I think I am missing a very basic thing.

Solution: In C++  we can increment line but in Python I am not sure how to achieve this. So as of now, I am writing old line than new line. But in the new file, I want only the new line.

Example:

```
M0 38 A 19 40 DATA2 L=4e-08 W=3e-07 nf=1 m=1 $X=170 $Y=140 $D=8
M0 VBN A 19 40 TEMP2 L=4e-08 W=3e-07 nf=1 m=1 $X=170 $Y=140 $D=8
```

The code which i tried is the following:

```
def parsefile():
    fp = open("File1", "rb+")
    update_file = "File1" + "_update"
    fp_latest = open(update_file, "wb+")  
    for line in fp:
        if line.find("DATA1") == -1:
            fp_latest.write(line)
        if line.find("DATA1") != -1:
            line = line.split()
            pin_name = find_pin_order(line[1])
            update_line = "DATA " + line[1] + " " + pin_name
            fp_latest.write(update_line)
            line = ''.join(line) 
         if line.find("DATA2") != -1:
            line_data = line.split()
            line_data[1] = "TEMP2"
            line_data =' '.join(line_data)
            fp_latest.write(line_data)
         if line.find("DATA3") != -1:
            line_data = line.split()
            line_data[1] = "TEMP3"
            line_data =' '.join(line_data)
            fp_latest.write(line_data)

 fp_latest.close()
 fp.close()
```

Comment: It's worth noting that when you are working with files in Python, it is best to use [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4).

Comment: Likewise, if you want to check something is not in a string, the best way to do that is to use `if not "string" in line`, rather than using `line.find()`:. There are also symptoms of copy/paste coding here - you are doing the same thing with slightly different variables multiple times - you should extract that functionality out into a loop and/or function.

Comment: `if line.find("DAT1") != -1:` - did you really mean that to be "DAT1" and not "DATA1"? and why not just use `else:` instead?

Comment: What output are you looking for?  Currently, if `DATA1` and `DATA2` both show up in the input line, your output file will get two lines written.  Is that what you intend to do?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your current code is that your first `if` block, which checks for `"DATA1"` and writes the line out if it is not found runs when `"DATA2"` or `"DATA3"` is present. Since those have their own blocks, the line ends up being duplicated in two different forms.

Here's a minimal modification of your loop that should work:

```
for line in fp:
    if line.find("DATA1") != -1:
        data = line.split()
        pin_name = find_pin_order(data[1])
        line = "DATA " + data[1] + " " + pin_name
    if line.find("DATA2") != -1:
        data = line.split()
        data[1] = "TEMP2"
        line =' '.join(data)
    if line.find("DATA3") != -1:
        data = line.split()
        data[1] = "TEMP3"
        line =' '.join(data)

    fp_latest.write(line)
```

This ensures that only one line is written because there's only a single `write()` call in the code. The special cases simply modify the line that is to be written. I'm not sure I understand the modifications you want to have done in those cases, so there may be more bugs there.

One thing that might help would be to make the second and third `if` statements into `elif` statements instead. This would ensure that only one of them would be run (though if you know your file will never have multiple `DATA` entries on a single line, this may not be necessary).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a new line in a file replacing the old content that has been readed last time, you can use the file.seek() method for moving arround the file, there is an example.

```
with open("myFile.txt", "r+") as f:
    offset = 0
    lines = f.readlines()
    for oldLine in lines:
            ... calculate the new line value ...
            f.seek(offset)
            f.write(newLine)
            offset += len(newLine)
            f.seek(offset)
```